# How to show commands submission into thread pool in sequence diagram

Tags: multithreading, uml, threadpool, sequence-diagram, command-pattern

I'm preparing sequence diagram. where tasks created as commands according to command design pattern are submitted into thread pool and executed.

Let's assume that command execute some methods form Data class.

And here's my problems:

I don't know if i should draw command object specifically, or just simple 'submitTask()' message passed from invoker into thread pool.

I dont't know if i should draw workerThread object, or just simplify it, to thead pool calling Data class functions.

I don't know how to represent queueing commands into thread pool, and then their executions.

I know, a lil bit chaotic, mayby the last question is the most important.
Looking forward for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any SD does not show *any* possible message combination but *one single scenario.* So just think which ones are most important and create the according diagrams.

There are many, many ways to actually implement your queue. This would be some sample implementation:

[image]

`Threading` has two ports. One for queuing requests and one to get them out again.

Comment: I think I don't understand. It is one single scenario. Passing command into thread pool and then execution of this task by worker thread.

Comment: Thank you, that's one of the way i was considering, but wasn't sure.

Comment: I doubt if this is a valid SD and I don't understand your intentions. The first `queue()` triggers a message from Threading to Worker, but it is a dashed arrow. I know that dashed arrows are used for create-messages and return-messages, but this one is neither. Or is it the reply to `dequeue()`?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl It was made on the fly. You need to extend the top left invocation. I'll see if that's still around to fix it.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I made an update using ports. Hope that complies now.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what's happening. Nice solution using these ports. Never seen before. Don't know if it's UML compliant.  +1

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl EA lets me do that and they are not too bad with UML compliance. Will see where it's in the specs...

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Fig. 17.22 on p. 591 of UML 2.5