# Can you represent a port as a lifeline in UML sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, port, sequence-diagram

In section "17.3.4.1 Lifeline" of UML Specification 2.5.1, it writes:

*"If the name is ‘self’, then the Lifeline represents the object of the classifier that encloses the Interaction that owns the Lifeline. Ports of the encloser may be shown separately even when self is included."*

Unfortunately, there is no example of how to show a port in a sequence diagram. Now, does this statement mean that we can represent ports of the class as a lifeline, or is there any other notation to show the ports in a sequence diagram?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841140/how-to-show-commands-submission-into-thread-pool-in-sequence-diagram (left life line has two ports shown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we can represent ports of the class as a lifeline ... ?

A *Lifeline* represents a *ConnectableElement* (§17.12.17.4 of [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)). A *Port* is a *Property* (§ 11.8.14.3) which is a *ConnectableElement* (§9.9.17.3), so a *Port* is a *ConnectableElement* and the answer is yes

> Ports of the encloser may be shown separately even when self is included.

This is a precision saying there is no restriction for the ports of the encloser, to avoid possible doubt